# Set Default Block Size for Specific Path

Tags: alluxio

how can I set default block size for a specific path? I don't know which property to be set in './alluxio fsadmiin pathConf ' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default block size for Alluxio files with `alluxio.user.block.size.bytes.default` and the default size is 64MB.

You can read more about this property and other related properties here: https://docs.alluxio.io/os/user/stable/en/reference/Properties-List.html#alluxio.user.block.size.bytes.default